# Hide sh: -c error messages when calling “system” in c++ Linux

Tags: c++, linux, bash

I'm using system to execute a command with it's arguments. I don't want to use exec/fork. 
When I have unmatched quotes in my command this error appears:

```
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

How do I suppress these *shell's* error messages?  I tried adding `>/dev/null 2>&1` at the end of the invalid command but it doesn't suppress the shell error message.  For background, I'm running user supplied commands which may or may not be valid.  I can't know in advance if they'll be valid or not, but I want to suppress the error messages regardless.

Here's an example of code that generates the type of error I'm trying to suppress:

```
int main()
{
   // This command is meant to be invalid as I'm trying to suppress the shell syntax error message
   system("date ' >/dev/null 2>&1");
   return 0;
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Why are you running commands with invalid syntax in the first place?

Comment: The reason your `>/dev/null 2>&1` doesn't work is because that's attempting to redirect the output of `date`, but the error being generated is coming from the shell itself, not your date command.  Out of curiosity, why are you attempting to run invalid commands anyways?

Comment: I am getting commands from user!

Comment: @sfallahdoost - So how will the user know that the command was invalid?

Comment: where is the code to get command from user?

Comment: @sfallahdoost - So you let the user enter anything, and your program runs the command, unchecked?  Isn't that kind of ... umm.. dangerous?

Comment: i restrict allowed commands. i use system for limited number of commands such as ifconfig and date

Comment: Why don't you want to use `fork` & `execve` ?

Comment: @sfallahdoost, if your system for restricting commands isn't sufficient to require that commands have valid (shell) syntax, it's almost certainly not sufficient to be secure. Better to follow Basile's advice and not have a shell involved at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think that `system` forks a process and then executes the command you've provided. The new process inherits the descriptor from its parent and that new process is writing in its standard error.

So, this code snippet may do what you want:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int duperr;
    duperr = dup(2);
    close(2); /* close stderr so the new process can't output the error */
    system("date '");
    dup2(duperr, 2);
    close(duperr);
    /* here you can use stderr again */
    write(2, "hello world\n", 12);
    return 0;
}
```

---

To make writes to stderr be silently suppressed, you can output the errors to `/dev/null`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int devnull_fd, duperr_fd;
    /* get a descriptor to /dev/null (devnull_fd) */
    devnull_fd = open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
    /* save a descriptor "pointing" to the actual stderr (duperr_fd) */
    duperr_fd = dup(STDERR_FILENO);
    /* now STDERR_FILENO "points" to "/dev/null" */
    dup2(devnull_fd, STDERR_FILENO); 

    system("date '");
    /* restore stderr */
    dup2(duperr_fd, STDERR_FILENO);
    close(duperr_fd);
    close(devnull_fd);
    /* here you can use stderr again */
    write(STDERR_FILENO, "hello world\n", 12);
    return 0;
}
```

Remember to check the return value of the function calls.

Answer (score 1):

The logical problem is that you're not redirecting anything because the part `>/dev/null 2>&1` ends up being contained in a single-quoted part.

The string however doesn't end and therefore bash complains on stderr.

The solution for this specific case is to quote single-quotes by preceding them with a backslash, i.e. to call `system("date \\' >/dev/null 2>&1")`. Note however that bash exact quoting rules are a small nightmare.

A workaround I can think to in general is to save the command in a file, say `cmd.txt`, and then execute

```
system("bash < cmd.txt >/dev/null 2>&1");
```

May be this can be done also with `bash -c` without creating the file but I simply was not able to make any sense of single quote escaping rules for `-c` and I'm not going to waste neurons on the totally broken `bash` grammar.

Comment: if i preceding them with a backslash, correct commands don't execute successfully

Comment: @sfallahdoost: I can only think to an ugly workaround... see edit.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to run a correct command, then remove the quote, so

```
  system("date >/dev/null 2>&1");
```

However, what is the point of running that? If (your `PATH` is common enough so that...) `date` is indeed `/bin/date` (see [date(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html)...) its only effect is to produce some output, and you are discarding it by redirecting it to `/dev/null`. So the only visible effect of your call to `system` is to spend several millions of CPU cycles. Of course, in weird cases, it could fail (e.g. because `/bin/sh` does not exist, `/bin/date` does not exist, `fork` has failed, etc...) ....

Maybe you are coding a shell. Then you should parse the command and do `fork`  & `execve` .....

If you want to get the output of some command like `date`, better use [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) with `pclose`. In the particular case of the `date` it is much better to use [time(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html), [localtime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3.html), [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) (then you don't need to depend upon an external command, and you won't need to use `popen`)

If you really want to suppress the output of the shell started by `system` you could do the `fork`  & `execve` (of `bin/sh -c`) yourself and redirect the standard and error outputs (to a file descriptor opening `/dev/null`) with `dup2`. See also [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) & [wordexp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html)

Maybe embedding an interpreter in your application (e.g. [lua](http://lua.org/) or [guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/)) would be more sensible (assuming you don't care about user mistakes)

Comment: I know but i'm getting commands as a input from users. i want to show correct error messages to user.

Comment: And what if your user input `rm -rf $HOME`

Comment: i restrict allowed commands. i use system for limited number of commands such as ifconfig and date

Comment: What "correct error message" do you expect to show from this sort of error? The one printed by `sh` seems pretty accurate to me. I doubt you can do better without parsing the command yourself. And if you're going to parse the command yourself, you may as well just pass the parsed arguments directly to `exec` and skip all the `system` nonsense entirely.

Comment: you're right, it's accurate. but I want to show my own error messages not sh error messages.

Comment: Then you need to code your own shell-like stuff, including `fork` & `execve`

Comment: if i use exec, i have to parse all arguments. i check only the first token and user is not allowed to use pipe , >> ,...

Comment: What if the user types: `sash -c 'rm -rf $HOME'`

Comment: sash is not allowed in the beginning of command. limited number of commands such as date and ifconfig are executed with system. i don't have sufficient time to parse these two commands. other commands are executed with exec.

Comment: @sfallahdoost, and can you correctly handle `date -c "$(rm -rf $HOME)"`?

Comment: @sfallahdoost, ...point being that you're playing a dangerous game, and to play it *well* means either that you need to restrict the user unreasonably (ruling out legitimate date format strings because they contain characters that would be meaningful to the shell in other positions) or you do the work of positional parsing, which eliminates any ease-of-implementation advantage you might otherwise get from `system()`.

Comment: thanks Charles...special character like $ is not allowed. I will use j.a. solution

Comment: But some users might have file names or directory names with a `$` inside (this is bad taste, but it is not forbidden)